# When clicking a button, the OnClientClick event does not raise

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, onclientclick

I have a js function like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function Cols() {
           rows = document.getElementById("GridView1").rows;
           for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
               rows[i].cells[8].style.visibility = "visible";
               rows[i].cells[9].style.visibility = "visible";
               rows[i].cells[10].style.visibility = "visible";
               rows[i].cells[11].style.visibility = "visible";
               rows[i].cells[12].style.visibility = "visible";
               rows[i].cells[13].style.visibility = "visible";
               rows[i].cells[14].style.visibility = "visible";
           }
       }

</script>
```

And this button with an OnClientClick event:

```
<asp:Button ID="Add_Button" runat="server" OnClick="Add_Button_Click" Text="Add New Record" OnClientClick="Cols()" />
```

The cells in my function refers to the Gridview columns I want to make visible on the Client side before going to my OnClick event on the server side which makes my GridView footer row visible, the footer row is used to insert a new row.

EDIT:
So here is my original problem: When clicking the button I wanted to make the other columns visible and then make the footer row visible in the same click event. However after the event has been raised the extra columns are made visible but not the footer row until I click the button a second time.

Here is my Click event:

```
protected void Add_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.FooterRow.Visible == false)
            {

                GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
                Add_Button.Text = "Cancel";
                Panel2.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
                Add_Button.Text = "Add New Record";
                GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
                GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
                GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = false;
                GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = false;
                GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
                GridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
                GridView1.Columns[16].Visible = false; 
            }

    }
```

However, when I click the button my OnClick event is raised but not the OnClientClick. Why is this happening?

Comment: have you tried adding the RegisterClientScriptBlock in the button onclick event on the server side? the postback causes the changes made by the js function to revert back.

Comment: The column index in server side and client side is totally different. Are you sure that the column you are trying to make visible are rendered in the client browser? You can try to use Developer Tool or Inspect Element on the browser to check. I'm questioning because if you set Column visible to false in server side, that column will not be rendered in the client side. Hence your column index in your javascript may not be the right index that you want.

Comment: Why not do this all server side or all client side? It seems to make no sense to me to split between the two  in this instance. Also note that `style.visibility = "visible"` is very different to `GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;` (and different again to `style.display= "none"` )

Comment: Expanding on the above: the server side `GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false` results in **no HTML** being rendered for that element so there is nothing for client side script to interact with.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is allow some columns and the footer row to be made visible on button click. If I do it all server side on first button click the columns are made visible but not the footer row until the button is clicked again. I haven't tried it all client side yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the default action of the button, namely the postback.

Change it to this (note the return false part):

```
<asp:Button ID="Add_Button" runat="server" OnClick="Add_Button_Click" Text="Add New Record" OnClientClick="Cols(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What tells you that the `OnClientClick` event is NOT raised?
As far as I can tell it is raised, but then, immediately after, you post back to the server to execute the `OnClick` event on the server.

So you don't see the `Cols()` function being executed.

Try to end the `Cols()` function this way:

```
return false; // prevent the OnClick event from being fired
```

This way, only the `OnClientClick` event is fired and not the `OnClick` event.
Obviously, it does not make sense to keep both at this point.
The only case where both make sense is a JS function like this:

```
return confirm("Are you sure to execute OnClick?");
```

If the user chooses "NO" he stays on the page, otherwise the post back happens.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option, get rid of the client side all together and change your button click to the following:

```
protected void Add_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Add_Button.Text != "Cancel") //Add Record
    {
        GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
        Add_Button.Text = "Cancel";
        Panel2.Visible = false;
    }
    else //Cancel
    {
         GridView1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
         Add_Button.Text = "Add New Record";
         GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;
         GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false;
         /*etc*/ 
    }
}
```

**Here is another Servierside option that may be more robust**

```
protected void Add_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool visibility = false;
    string buttonText = string.empty;
    if (Add_Button.Text != "Cancel") //Add Record
    {
        visibility = true;
        buttonText = "Cancel";
        Panel2.Visible = false;
    }
    else //Cancel
    {
        visibility = false;
        buttonText = "Add New Record";
    }

    Add_Button.Text = buttonText;
    ridView1.FooterRow.Visible = visibility;
    GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = visibility;
    GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = visibility;
    /*etc*/ 
}
```

You really aren't gaining anything with something happening client side immediately followed by a post back.

Your other option is to do it all client side. I don't know enough about you `Grdiveiw` to give a customized answer, but here are the basics of what you need to do:

- When the grid is generated add a CSS class to the column cells you want to hide, and the footer row with `display:none`
- Use javascript to remove the class to show the hidden elements and change the text of your button.

If your grid has a fixed number of columns you could even get tricky and just use clever CSS to hide the footer and columns without having to do anything serverside.

Comment: In my gridview the extra columns are hidden for aesthetic reasons, so what I'm trying to accomplish is to allow the button click to make these columns visible AND the footer row, however when I put it all in the click event, on first click the columns are made visible but not the footer row until the button is clicked again.

Comment: The code I have provided will do what you want. The reason it was  taking two cliks for you is that you were checking the visibility of the footer to display the columns, and this does not change untill you have clicked the button. I have changed the check to the button text.

Comment: I used your second suggestion and what happened is it manages to change the visibility of the columns but not the footer row.

Comment: Is the footer row not appearing on "add" or is it not disappearing on "cancel"? As a debug test, let everything appear on page load and check that the footer is being generated. Perhaps add your Gridview mark up to your question.